# How can add the function (lenght)

Tags: javascript

I have a  that generates the entry of people on a bus (function increment()) and is recorded in function save().
how can i display the total people(function total() in the alert)?

```js
var count = 0
var saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
var countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")


function increment() {
    count += 1
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function save() {
    let countStr = count + " - "
    saveEl.textContent += countStr
    countEl.textContent = 0
    count = 0
}

function total(){

    alert(____?____)

}
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Wouldn't it just be `alert(count)`?

Comment: if put alert(count) return the number of click i have done on the moment at function increment. And if write alert(coun.lenght) show undefined

Comment: Because you're misspelling `lenght`. It should be `length`.